# How can I improve unbalanced error residuals in mixed-model negative binomial regression?

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, unbalanced-classes, negative-binomial-distribution

I wish to determine the factors that influence seedling density. The density data are highly right-skewed with mostly zeros; values vary from 0-35. Potential influencing factors measured were the use of fire in the year before seed drop (binary), the abundance of the trees that produced the seedlings, and the abundance of several kinds of competing vegetation.  Measurements were made over 15 yrs at irregular intervals and the design is by no means balanced. Observations were made 3 times on average per location and I am using Location as a random variable. I have been using a negative binomial mixed model via glmer.nb() and have found significant predictors but error residuals are unbalanced: min = -0.9, max=5. Should I just live with the unbalanced error residuals, or try another approach?

Comment: For checking nb residuals, including problems such as zero-inflation, consider the DHARMa package, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unbalanced" residuals are not a problem at all, especially for negative binomial regression. As a matter of fact, they should be expected, since your model fit estimates the conditional mean of your data generating process.

Try this yourself: take a reasonable expectation and overdispersion parameter, then sample as many data points from the corresponding negative binomial distribution as you have in your data. The minimum of these samples will be much closer to the mean than the maximum - because the negative binomial is skewed, after all.

Actually, when you write about many zeros, you may want to look at *zero-inflated* models, either Poisson or negative binomial.